# JS: how to remove "spammy invisible chars"?

Tags: javascript, utf-8

Some user is flooding with some chars that bypass regex filters.
when I paste that chars into UTF8 editor, they look same (except the flood version is not selectable completly: it seems to be some invisible chars inserted

[image]

And when you switch to ANSI encodage, you clearly see the difference of the 2 words
liebehomo
lâ€iâ€ebâ€ehâ€oâ€mo

When I paste that spammy word into developer tool, I get

[image]

s.length gives 14 and not 9 !

[image]

So my question is: how would it be possible to filter these spammy words that contains some strange chars ?

Comment: It's been a while since I messed with this but have you tried splitting the string? And then testing each char through a loop?

Comment: In case anyone who runs into the same issue sees this, the following seems to work: `str.replace(/\p{C}/gu, '');`. Note that the `u` flag is required for this to work. I'm not sure if this works for all invisible characters, though (kinda hard to test)

Answer (score 0):

Probably as simple as replacing any non-printable character first:

```
string = string.replace(/[^ -~]+/g, "");
```

```js
document.getElementById('demo').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    e.target.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML.replace(/[^ -~]+/g, "");
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<textarea id="demo"></textarea>
```

Comment: That's not checking for printable characters, but rather for ASCII characters only.

Comment: Could you explain that regex please ?